# convert complex xml feed to csv using php

Tags: php, xml

i have a xml data feed which needs to be accessed using curl. i tried to get the curl output and use the XMLReader to read each node but it didnt work. Because when  i loaded the feed using curl it takes around 1-2 minutes because its quite big.

so what i thought was to download the feed to my server and convert it to csv and upload it to my database. so i can use it with a cron to keep my database updated.

i found this code which seems to work fine in normal xml feeds but it doesn't seem to be working for my feed.

in this feed

```
<cars>
<car>
 <color>blue</color>
 <price>2000</price>
</car>
<car>
 <color>red</color>
 <price>10000</price>
</car> 
<car>
 <color>black</color>
 <price>5000</price>
</car>
</cars>
```

when i use the below code it works.

```
$filexml='cars.xml';
if (file_exists($filexml)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
$f = fopen('cars.csv', 'w');
foreach ($xml->car as $car) {
    fputcsv($f, get_object_vars($car),',','"');
}
fclose($f);
}
```

but when it comes to the below feed how do i change the above code to add the model, pictures,images,types.... to the csv?

```
 <cars>
<car>
 <color>blue</color>
 <price>2000</price>
 <model />
  <pictures>
    <image>1.jpg</image>
    <image>2.jpg</image>
  </pictures>
  <type>
   <bodykit>yes</bodykit>
   <turbo>no</turbo>
   <sound>surround</sound>
 </type>
</car>
<car>
 <color>red</color>
 <price>10000</price>
<model>GTX</model>
  <pictures>
    <image>5.jpg</image>
  </pictures>
  <type>
   <bodykit>yes</bodykit>
   <turbo>no</turbo>
   <sound>no</sound>
 </type>
 </car> 
 <car>
 <color>black</color>
 <price>5000</price>
 <model>GTX</model>
  <pictures>
    <image>5.jpg</image>
    <image>8.jpg</image>
  </pictures>
  <type>
   <bodykit>yes</bodykit>
   <turbo>no</turbo>
   <sound>surround</sound>
 </type>
</car>
</cars>
```

any help or thoughts will be appreciated...

Comment: CSV is a flat format, so you have to choose how to deal with XML tree structure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you may try

```
$filexml='cars.xml';

    if (file_exists($filexml)) 
           {
       $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
       $f = fopen('cars.csv', 'w');
       createCsv($xml, $f);
       fclose($f);
    }

    function createCsv($xml,$f)
    {

        foreach ($xml->children() as $car) 
        {

           $hasChild = (count($car->children()) > 0)?true:false;

        if( ! $hasChild)
        {
           $put_arr = array($car->getName(),$car); 
           fputcsv($f, $put_arr ,',','"');

        }
        else
        {
         createCsv($car, $f);
        }
     }

    }
```

Comment: cool..it gets all the details in 2 columns. is it possible like to get the the first rows with the node names and data in each row?

Comment: Hmm can you give me the sample output .. I will like to try that